# Renaming two files in multiple folders by adding suffix and prefix

Tags: shell, perl

I have multiple folders where two files are present.

For example,  `123.jpg`, `456.jpg` under folder `ABC`. I want to rename the files to `IT1_ABC_123.v1.jpg` and `IT2_ABC_456.v1.jpg`. Similarly,  other folders have two files.

How can I do this in shell or Perl?

Comment: Please show your effort.

Comment: What is the idea behind the `IT1` and `IT2` prefix?

Comment: IT1and IT2 are two iterations of one test case.

Comment: I am getting following O/P    [root@localhost]# python test.py
> /home/abc/test.py(5)<module>()
-> for subdirs in subdirs:
(Pdb)

Comment: @Raj2015 Don't post code in comments. [Edit] your question and include the code there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using shell *and* perl:

```
mkdir /tmp/test; cd $_
mkdir ABC DEF
touch {ABC,DEF}/{123,456}.jpg   #creates four files, two in each directory
find|perl -nlE's,((.*)/(.+))/((123|456).jpg),$1/IT@{[++$n]}_$3_$4,&&say"$&\n$_\n"'

./ABC/123.jpg
./ABC/IT1_ABC_123.jpg

./ABC/456.jpg
./ABC/IT2_ABC_456.jpg

./DEF/123.jpg
./DEF/IT3_DEF_123.jpg

./DEF/456.jpg
./DEF/IT4_DEF_456.jpg
```

Now, after confirming this is what you want, replace the `say` with a `rename`:

```
find|perl -nlE's,((.*)/(.+))/((123|456).jpg),$1/IT@{[++$n]}_$3_$4, and rename$&,$_'
```

The new filenames:

```
find -type f
./ABC/IT1_ABC_123.jpg
./ABC/IT2_ABC_456.jpg
./DEF/IT3_DEF_123.jpg
./DEF/IT4_DEF_456.jpg
```

This will find filenames with 123.jpg or 456.jpg and rename them.

`s,,,` is the search-replace and it returns 1 (the number of changes it made) which again leads to the right side of the `and` being done (the rename).

Filenames that doesn't match 123.jpg or 456.jpg isn't renamed since `s,,,` will return 0 and the `and` is "short cutted" since it then logically cannot be true with a false (0) left side. So then the rename is *not* executed.

This variant does the same, but might be easier to read:

```
find|perl -nlE 'rename$&,$_ if s,((.*)/(.+))/((123|456).jpg),$1/IT@{[++$n]}_$3_$4,'
```

I have found this pattern useful in many cases of mass renamings. Also, dedicated software for mass renaming with GUIs exists, which for some might be easier to use.

Rewritten as a program abc.pl, it could be:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while(<>){
  chomp;
  next if not s,((.*)/([A-Z]{3}))/(\d{3}\.jpg),$1/IT@{[++$n]}_$3_$4,;
  print "Found:    $&\nNew name: $_\n\n";
 #rename $&, $_;
}
```

Run:

```
find|perl abc.pl
```

Comment: Thanks for this..Actually there are multiple folders like ABC,DEF,GHI....XYZ.And inside each of these folders only two files are present.And each of these two files are unique..let's says 123.jpg,456.jpg in ABC are present,then in XYZ folders 987.jpg and 675.jpg is present.So I want to rename all these unique  files present in unique folders to above syntax.Like 123.jpg should be renamed to IT1_ABC_123.v2.jpg and 456.jpg should be renamed to IT2_ABC_456.v2.jpg.

Comment: The `find` will run through any subfolder. Change `find` to `find ???`  (yes, three question marks) to run through any folder with a name of three chars. You could replace `123|456` with `\d{3}` to match any three digits, not just 123 and 456. ( about _"Thanks for this"_...upvote is the best kind of thanks on stackoverflow.com, that up-arrowy symbol above the number on the top left side of my answer ;-)

Comment: Hi Kjetil..I am getting syntax errors..
find???|perl -nlE's((.*)/(.+))/((d{3}).jpg),$1/IT@{[++$n]}_$3_$4,&&say"$&\n$_\n"'
find???|perl -nlE's((.*)/(.+))/((d{3}).jpg),$1/IT@{[++$n]}_$3_$4, and rename$&,$_'


bash-3.2# perl abc.pl
syntax error at abc.pl line 4, near "(."
Execution of abc.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: Weeeeell, you left out a space before `???` and a comma behind the first `s` and maybe more. (Something added to my answer above)

Comment: bash-3.2# find|perl a.pl
find: insufficient number of arguments
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list         Still getting errors:(

Comment: Then you don't have a normal gnu find command (like most often in Linux and other shells) and that's where I can't find more time on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in core Perl using the [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html), [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html), and [File::Copy](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html) modules. You can test it out with the script below. It won't make any changes until you uncomment the line with the "move" function.

```
#! perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename;
use File::Copy;
use File::Find;

my $root_dir = '/path/to/main/folder';

# Recursively searches for all files below the $root_dir
my @fileset;
find(
    sub {

        # Get the absolute file path
        my $path = $File::Find::name;

        # Only capture the path if not a directory
        # You can add any number of conditions here
        if (!-d $path) {
            push @fileset, $path;
        }
    },
    $root_dir
);

# set the IT counter in new file name
my $int = 1;

# list of all possible file suffixes to have fileparse() look for. It will 
# capture the end of the file path verbatim (including the period) if it's 
# in this array 
my @suffixes = ('.jpg', '.txt');

my $previous_dir;
foreach my $old_path (@fileset) {

    # split apart the basename of the file, the directory path, and the file suffix
    my ($basename, $parent_dir, $suffix) = fileparse($old_path, @suffixes);

    # strip off trailing slash so fileparse() will capture parent dir name correctly
    $parent_dir =~ s{[/]$}{};

    # capture just the name of the parent directory
    my $parent_name = fileparse($parent_dir);

    # Assemble the new path
    my $new_path = $parent_dir . '/IT' . $int . '_' 
                 . $parent_name . '_' . "$basename.v1" . $suffix;

    # Move the file to rename (this is safer than using rename() for cross-platform)
    # move $old_path, $new_path;

    print "OLD PATH: $old_path\n";
    print "NEW PATH: $new_path\n\n";

    # Reset counter when dir changes
    if (!$previous_dir) {
        $previous_dir = $parent_dir; # set previous_dir on first loop
    }
    elsif($previous_dir ne $parent_dir) {
        $previous_dir = $parent_dir; # update previous_dir to check next loop
        $int = 0; # reset counter
    }

    $int++; # iterate the counter
}
```

**Edit 2018-07-12:** I've updated the answer to show how to reset the counter when the directory changes by evaluating the current path with the one used in the previous loop and updating accordingly. This is not tested so it may need some adjustments.

Given the abc/def examples given, the output should look something like this:

```
OLD PATH: /path/to/main/folder/abc/123.jpg
NEW PATH: /path/to/main/folder/abc/IT1_abc_123.v1.jpg

OLD PATH: /path/to/main/folder/abc/456.txt
NEW PATH: /path/to/main/folder/abc/IT2_abc_456.v1.jpg

OLD PATH: /path/to/main/folder/def/123.jpg
NEW PATH: /path/to/main/folder/def/IT1_def_123.v1.jpg

OLD PATH: /path/to/main/folder/def/456.jpg
NEW PATH: /path/to/main/folder/def/IT2_def_456.v1.jpg
```

Comment: :When I have two or more folders under parent folder it is renaming file as IT1,IT2,IT3,IT4.IT5 etc.But my requirement was for each subfolder under parent folder,there are only two files and they should be renamed as IT1 and IT2.I don't want IT3 and IT4 for the second subfolder.

Comment: :Can you please answer the above query?

Comment: Hi @Raj2015, I've updated my answer to show how to reset the counter by comparing the directory path of the current file with the one from the previous loop. I only did a basic check to see if it runs, so I recommend testing it out thoroughly first.

Comment: Hi @Interduo I executed the above code.It works fne for the first folder but for the second folder I see it renames the file as IT3 and IT1.

Comment: Hi @Raj2015, you may need to sort the `@fileset` array before looping through it. Failing that, you'll have to take a closer look at the comparison between `$previous_dir` and `$parent_dir`. You may need to use a regular expression instead of the `ne` operator to get the match to work as intended.